# Template for multiple environment terragrunt gcp project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terragrunt

I want to start a new Terraform project that will deploy resources on a GCP account. I want to use Terragrunt to provision multiple environments (test,dev,prod).

Essentially each environment will be the same except the names of the resources will have a prefix (environment name) and the resources will be in another region. I also want to keep it DRY with terragrunt.

So far I only have this desired folder structure:

```
project
└── env
    └── test
    └── dev
    └── prod
└── resources
    └── vpc
    └── pubsub
    └── cloudrun
    └── resource4
```

I am confused by Terragrunt and Terraform is overwhelming. I have little experience with it, I mostly know CloudFormation on AWS.

So where should I put terragrunt.hcl file and what should be inside it? Where do I store the resources variables and how to I force resources to use env variables (region and prefix). What command should I use to deploy the specific environment?

Comment: I would recommend you read the guide on terraform:
https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example. Azure is the provider here but that doesn't change the way modules are organized.

This assumes you're using local TF state (probably you'd want to set up a [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html)).

Also modules are referenced from the local file system here. You can store them in a separate Git repo (Terragrunt suggested way) for versioning.

An example reusable module at `project/resources/resource_group/main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.26"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-resource-group"
  location = var.location

  tags = {
    project     = var.project
    environment = var.environment
    region      = var.location
  }
}

# I've included variables and outputs in the same file, 
# but it's recommended to put them into separate 
# variables.tf and outputs.tf respectively.

variable "project" {
  type        = string
  description = "Project name"
}

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "Environment (dev / stage / prod)"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The Azure Region where the Resource Group should exist"
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.name
}
```

An example usage of the module in a given environment. Module path is `project/test/resource_group/terragrunt.hcl`:

```
generate "provider" {
  path = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents = <<EOF
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
EOF
}

terraform {
  source = "../../resources//resource_group"
}

inputs = {
  project = "myapp"
  environment = "test"
  location = "East US"
}
```

To deploy that specific module (likely it will have more than one resource, unlike in my example), you run `terragrunt apply` from `project/test/resource_group`.

Alternatively you can execute multiple modules by running [`terragrunt apply-all`](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/features/execute-terraform-commands-on-multiple-modules-at-once/) from `project/test`.

Honestly, if you're going to use it for projects in production, you better go through Terragrunt documentation, it's quite good.

Comment: But why do I need to create a folder for each resource inside every environment folder? I just need 2 different variables for each environment (prefix and region).

Comment: Also is terragrunt.hcl the same as terraform.tfvars? Has the syntax changed?

Comment: I'm following this tutorial https://harjot.me/blog/deploying-docker-containers-to-gke-using-terraform/ is that okay?

Comment: @KatranPlague You create a folder for each reusable module inside every environment folder, not for each resource. Ideally you'll have (not so many) modules. For example you may have modules: `network`, `database`, `fronend_app`, `backend_app`. Each module will contain one or many terraform resources. `terragrunt.hcl` is a way to configure a reusable module and it is not the same as `terraform.tfvars`. You can use it not only for passing input variables but also to include dependencies (other modules) and shared bits of configuration.